# implicit object parameter and this pointer

Tags: c++, methods, this, non-static, ref-qualifier

With reference to [Non-static member functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions), under

> const-, volatile-, and ref-qualified member functions

it is mentioned:

> A non-static member function can be declared with no ref-qualifier,
>   with an lvalue ref-qualifier (the token & after the parameter list) or
>   the rvalue ref-qualifier (the token && after the parameter list).
>   During overload resolution, non-static cv-qualified member function of
>   class X is treated as follows:
>
> no ref-qualifier: the implicit object parameter has type lvalue reference to cv-qualified X and is additionally allowed to bind rvalue implied object argument
>
> lvalue ref-qualifier: the implicit object parameter has type lvalue
>   reference to cv-qualified X
>
> rvalue ref-qualifier: the implicit object parameter has type rvalue
>   reference to cv-qualified X
>
> Note: unlike cv-qualification, ref-qualification does not change the
>   properties of the this pointer: within a rvalue ref-qualified
>   function, *this remains an lvalue expression.

In this context, what is the difference between `the implicit object parameter` and `*this`?

Comment: I picture it as that the rvalue ref qualifier is removed from `*this` once the function is invoked. There probably is some rationale that you shouldn’t be able to call further rvalue qualified functions without an explicit `std::move(*this)`.

Comment: fyi it’s the `this` pointer that’s used for member function calls, not _the implicit object parameter_. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3819152edc5a1914

Comment: @Darklighter guess your code only goes to show that *this is always lvalue?

Comment: Yes, it showcases the _Note_ from your quote, but it also showcases that there is no difference between `memfun()` and `(*this).memfun()`, i.e. it’s not like the first form uses the type of _the implicit object paramter_ instead of the type of `*this` for overload resolution.

Comment: @Darklighter First form uses *implied object argument* which is the same as `(*this)`.

Comment: i think the question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32620750/why-are-rvalues-references-variables-not-rvalue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ref-qualifiers allow function overloading based on the type of reference of an expression.

Since there are no pointers (or references) to references in C++ `this` can’t point to a (n rvalue) reference, so `*this` can’t be an rvalue.

rvalue, lvalue and reference (intentionally) loose their relevance once the function is invoked.

Answer (score 2):

I think the difference can be illustrated with the following example:

When overload resolution selection relies on CV-qualifier `*this` will have an appropriate CV qualifier just like an implicit object parameter:

```
struct t_Tester
{
    constexpr auto Probe(/* t_Tester & param */) { return 1; }
    constexpr auto Probe(/* t_Tester const & param */) const { return 2; }
    constexpr auto Test(/* t_Tester const & param */) const { return (*this).Probe(); }
};

static_assert(2 == t_Tester{}.Test());
```

However when overload resolution selection relies on rvalue / lvalue reference qualifier `*this` will be still an lvalue even if implicit object parameter is an rvalue reference and the object itself is an rvalue:

```
struct t_Tester
{
    constexpr auto Probe(/* t_Tester & param */) & { return 1; }
    constexpr auto Probe(/* t_Tester && param */) && { return 2; }
    constexpr auto Test(/* t_Tester && param */) && { return (*this).Probe(); }
};

static_assert(1 == t_Tester{}.Test());
```

Note: Invoking function in class scope without using `this` pointer explicitly (like `return Probe();`) will use **implied object argument** (which is the same as `(*this)`) that should not be confused with **implicit object parameter** (which is just an invisible part of member function signatures used during overload resolution).

Comment: But once an rvalue qualified member function is invoked, what effect does the (initial) type of _the implicit object parameter_ have further on? I don’t think it has any.

Comment: @Darklighter I agree, *the implicit object parameter* is only important during overload resolution to build up complete function signatures.

Comment: I can't see any difference if writing `return (*this).Probe();` vs. `return Probe();`. I can't catch what is now the difference between *this and implicit object pointer. Can you explain a bit?

Comment: @Klaus The construct `return Probe()` uses *implied object argument*, which is the same as `(*this)`. While *implicit object parameter* is an imaginary part of non-static member function signatures.