# C++ rvalue reference requestion

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

I'm confusing with rvalue reference,
`is_rvalue_reference<decltype(a)>::value` indicates that the `a` variable is rvalue reference,
but can't pass it to `hello(int &&)` function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::boolalpha;
using std::string;
using std::is_rvalue_reference;
using std::move;


void hello(int && z) {};


int main(void) {
    int && a = 20;

    // a is_xvalue: true
    cout << "a is_xvalue: " << boolalpha << is_rvalue_reference<decltype(a)>::value << endl;

    // error C2664:  
    // 'void hello(int &&)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'int' to 'int &&'
    hello(a);       

    // compile ok.
    hello(move(a));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It may look strange but **all** named variables are lvalues. The moment you name `a` it has become an lvalue. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32620750/why-are-rvalues-references-variables-not-rvalue) for more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a` can be an identifier, but it can also be an expression. Identifiers and expressions are different things. Expressions have [types and value categories](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category), and identifiers only have types.

1. In the line

   ```
   int&& a = 20;
   ```

   `a` is an identifier (id-expression), not an expression. It has type `int&&` and it has no value category. `decltype(a)` will [return](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) the type `int&&`:

   > If the argument is an unparenthesized *id-expression* ..., then `decltype` yields the type of the entity named by this expression.
2. In the line

   ```
   hello(a);
   ```

   `a` is an expression, not an identifier. Now it has a value category, which is [*lvalue*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#lvalue), because `a` is a name of a variable (type doesn't matter):

   > The following expressions are *lvalue* expressions:
   >
   > - the name of a variable, ... Even if the variable's type is *rvalue* reference, the expression consisting of its name is an *lvalue* expression; ...

   It also has a type, which is `int`, because the standard [reads](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#type-1):

   > If an expression initially has the type “reference to `T`”, the type is adjusted to `T` prior to any further analysis.

   To treat `a` as an expression in `decltype`, you parenthesize it: `decltype((a))` will return `int&`, because for *lvalue* expressions of type `T` it returns `T&`:

   > If the argument is any other expression of type `T`, and
   >
   > - if the value category of expression is *xvalue*, then `decltype` yields `T&&`;
   > - if the value category of expression is *lvalue*, then `decltype` yields `T&`;

   `int&&` in `hello(int&&)` cannot bind to expressions with *lvalue* value category, compilation fails.
3. In the line

   ```
   hello(std::move(a));
   ```

   `std::move(a)` is an expression. Its value category is [*xvalue*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#xvalue):

   > The following expressions are *xvalue* expressions:
   >
   > - a function call or an overloaded operator expression, whose return type is rvalue reference to object, such as `std::move(x)`; ...

   Its type is also `int`. `decltype(std::move(a))` will return `int&&`, because for *xvalue* expressions of type `T` it returns `T&&`. `int&&` in `hello(int&&)` can bind to *xvalues* of type `int`, compilation succeeds.

Comment: Each C++ expression (an operator with its operands, a literal, `a variable name`, etc.) is characterized by two independent properties: a type and a value category.    The declaration `int a = 10` is not expression, but a variable name is expression, so `a` is expression and is lvalue, right?

Comment: @火狐狸, a variable name can be used in different contexts. In a declaration like `int a` it is not an expression, it is an identifier and it has no value category. When you use `a` to call a function, `a` becomes an lvalue expression. In an assignment like `b = a`, `a` is also an expression.

Comment: Upvote for explaining ```std::move``` in the answer!

Answer (score 4):

[Types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type) and [value categories](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) are two independent things.

> Each C++ expression (an operator with its operands, a literal, a variable name, etc.) is characterized by two independent properties: a *type* and a *value category*.

The type of `a` is `int&&`, i.e. rvalue-reference. But as a named variable, `a` is an lvalue and can't be bound to rvalue-reference. It seems confusing but try to consider them separately.

(emphasis mine)

> The following expressions are lvalue expressions:
>
> - the name of a variable, a function, a template parameter object (since C++20), or a data member, regardless of type, such as std::cin
>     or std::endl. **Even if the variable's type is rvalue reference, the
>     expression consisting of its name is an lvalue expression**;

Answer (score 4):

While `a` may seem like a r-value it is not.

`a` is itself an l-value that contains an r-value reference.

You can take the address of `a`, but you can't take the address of `move(a)`.

Please take a look at this [article](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_05.html) to really understand value categories specifically geared towards your question.

Comment: thank you very much, this `article` is what i want.