# Rvalue reference or lvalue?

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference

I've got a question of similiar nature like this one posted 5 years ago:
[Why are rvalues references variables not rvalue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32620750/why-are-rvalues-references-variables-not-rvalue)

My major concern is why can I do this:

```
int&& k = 3;
k++;
```

but I cannot do this:

```
(static_cast<int&&>(3))++;
```

I've always interpreted rvalue references as lvalues since rvalue reference variables are lvalues. But apparently that is not the case. Can someone explain to me why the `(static_cast<int&&>(3))++;` results in `using rvalue as lvalue` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The confusion is probably arising from the difference between `r-value` and `r-value reference`. The former is a value-category which only applies to *expressions*, while the latter is a type which applies to *variables* (technically it would need to be an r-value reference of some type, e.g. r-value reference to int).

So the difference between the snippets you've shown is not actually related to the *type* of the *variable*, but the *value-category* of the *expression*. Postfix `operator++` requires the value-category of the operand to be an l-value, regardless of the type of the operand.

In `k++`, the expression `k` is an l-value (roughly speaking, it has a name), which is its value-category. The *type* of the variable `k` is an r-value reference, but that's fine.

In `(static_cast<int&&>(3))++`, the expression `static_cast<int&&>(3)` is an r-value (it doesn't have a name), which is its value-category. Regardless of the *type* of `static_cast<int&&>` (which is `int`), the value-category is wrong, and so you get an error.

Note that the error message `using rvalue as lvalue` is referring to the value-category of the expression being used. It has nothing to do with the types of the variables.

Comment: I think it's important to note that expressions can't have reference types. The type of **variable** `k` is `int &&`, but the type of the **expression** `k` is just `int` (and that expression is an lvalue). This also means that the type of `static_cast<int&&>(3)` is `int` rather than `int &&`.

Comment: for anyone wanting to know more: a decent read: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Ok, reworded a fair bit. Should be clear now.

Comment: @cigien Looks good. I'll leave my comment there, since the "expressions can't have reference types" is what made it click for me when I was first learning it.

Comment: @cigien I'm slightly confused with "it doesn't have a name so it's rvalue" argument. Why does `(static_cast<int&>(k))++` work where `k` is some int variable ? I get that that expression returns reference to k and reference is defined as another name for an object, but then what is the difference between `static_cast<int&>` and `static_cast<int&&>` ? Both return reference, right ? To sum up, why does expression `static_cast<int&>` have a name ?

Comment: @domocar1 No, `(static_cast<int&&>(k))++;` returns a r-value reference, which is not modifiable, whereas `(static_cast<int&>(k))++;` returns an l-value reference, which is modifiable. `static_cast<int&>` casts to an l-value reference.

Comment: @cigien I'm sorry, I'm even more confused now. Rvalue reference is not modifiable ? Did you mean in general or just in this case ? Because, `int&& k=3; k++;` works.

Comment: @domocar1 Again, as I said in the answer, the difference is the *type* vs the *value-category*. In `int&& k=3;`, `k` is of type `r-value reference`, but the value-category is `l-value`. Whether an expression can be modified or not depends on the value-category, not the type.

Comment: @cigien Yeah, I get that part. The part I don't get; how do I know that `static_cast<int&&>(3)` is rvalue ? You stated that the reason is that it doesn't have a name. And that makes sense also. But then what does not makes sense to me is why does the expression `static_cast<int&>(k)` has a name ?

Comment: I'm sorry about the usage of "has a name". I wrote "roughly speaking ..." in the paragraph above because it's not *exactly* correct. The value-category of an expression is more specific than that (it's whether the expression can be *used* as an l-value). Perhaps this [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/q9rToG) will help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222177/discussion-between-domocar1-and-cigien).

Answer (score 0):

Because rvalue reference variable is lvalue

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#lvalue)

> **lvalue** Even if the variable's type is rvalue reference, the expression consisting of its name is an lvalue expression (but see Move-eligible expressions);